# Is complete regression testing achievable with Behavior Driver Development. (Jbehave/Cucmber)

Tags: cucumber, bdd, jbehave

Can we achieve regression tesing coverage with BDD using JBehave/Cucumber?
Please share your inputs that the complete regression testing is achievable with Behavior Driver Development. (Jbehave/Cucmber).

Answer (score 2):

In all but the most trivial products, it's impossible to perform complete regression testing.

Consider these acceptance criteria:

> Items can be replaced or refunded.

This leads to two scenarios; one where we refund the item, and one where we return it. Now let's add a bit more to that:

> Items are put in stock when returned or refunded, unless faulty.

Now we have four scenarios:

- The one where we replace the item and it's faulty
- The one where we refund the item and it's faulty
- The one where we replace the item and put it back in stock
- The one where we refund the item and put it back in stock.

Now let's add the criteria that a receipt must be in date. We need to check that refunds and replacements are both refused, but also that the item doesn't accidentally go back into stock, nor that any fault label is printed. So now we have eight scenarios.

Now let's think about the scenarios where we have a discount, and the ones where we can't scan the barcode, so we manually input the number, and the ones where the customer lost the receipt so we have to look it up using his loyalty card, and the ones where he paid by gift certificate...

Every scenario could, if the code was poorly designed, affect every other scenario. The number of potential combinations becomes exponential, very quickly.

We *hope* that the code is well-designed, and that the different aspects of behaviour are well-encapsulated. We *hope* that all the scenarios had been considered. However, if that was the case, we wouldn't be accidentally changing behaviour we didn't mean to, and we wouldn't need regression testing at all. So we know that at least some of the time, in most teams, changes to one scenario do affect changes in another.

Thinking about the responsibility of each piece of code can help to reduce this, which is why most teams practice both BDD and TDD (or BDD at a class level).

Additionally, it's impossible to ensure that every scenario has been thought of up-front, especially since every software project involves something new (or you wouldn't be doing it).

The only thing we can do is get *confidence* that the code works.

BDD is pretty good at giving us confidence. Not only does it help people to understand what the code does - so they are less likely to make mistakes and write bugs - but it also helps with automating the scenarios, so that there's less work for the testers, and they can focus more on looking for scenarios nobody's thought of yet (exploratory testing).

So, BDD can definitely help with regression testing... but nothing, not even BDD, can perform complete regression test coverage.

Comment: Thanks Lunivore for sharing your inputs. It gives better clarity to me. Since my application gonna have stable components with minimal changes to the flow, i thought of implementing BDD to automate it. Will be proceeding with the same now. great explanation :)